# Obfuscate or hide a number in html

Tags: php, html

I was tired of making football teams each week, so I wrote a simple php script to randomize teams. However I also want the teams to be fair, so I gave everyone a power ranking. Problem is I'd like to share the page with my mates, but I'd rather them not see how I ranked them if they decide to look at the web page's code. When selecting the players that are going to play in HTML you can see the ranking. How could I hide this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="players[Jon B][5]" value="" > Jon B<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="players[Mark S][8]" value="" > Mark S<br>
```

As you can see Jon has a power ranking of 5 and Mark 8
Also, I am just a beginner without too much programming experience.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the player ID instead and do all the calculations on the backend. Storing it like that on the frontend also allows anyone to simply use dev tools to change the value and submit anything they want.

Comment: I agree with @powerbuoy. You should just send the userID to the PHP script and store the power ranking in a database with their userid. Otherwise your code is pretty insecure and can be modified very easy to give an unfair advantage.

Comment: The real problem is that I hadn't thought about this  beforehand. Now that I'm done I don't want to make any huge changes due to laziness. Thanks!

Comment: Decided I'm just going to hide the data like this: If a player is ranked 5. It will be written 78590. Two random digits on either side of the 5 which will get trimmed off later. Maybe they could figure it out if they try hard, but if they go to that much trouble they win. Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: That's some high level security you got there! :P

Answer (score 3):

The only way to hide it is to keep the information in a database and only show them the results. Even if you hide something in the html, they can still see it by looking at the page source. However, they'll have no access to the database or the calculating formulas you'll have in php.

For example, let's say (for a simple example, that a ranking was determined by factors A + (1.5 x B). Your formula in PHP could be as follows and no one would be able to see it:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3;
$result = $a + ($b * 1.5);
echo $result;
```

Now, the only thing that will show up in the html is the actual result of 9.5. I'm assuming from the example that you're retrieving the values for `$a` & `$b` from a database, but I didn't want to get in to that here.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The values were just hard coded in because I know how good the players are so I just made up a ranking.

Comment: They key is, to do all of your calculations in php and only display the results. Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for isn't possible.  If your page requires the data, that data is viewable by anyone.

Put another way, you can't give someone information without them getting that information.

Your information must stay server-side, if you don't want it to be known.